# Best Practice in delivering processed image from server to client

Tags: amazon-web-services, protocols, server-side

There is a service which generate an image (1MB ~ 10MB sized) based on user request. It requires some calculation process and I would like to deliver generated image as quickly as possible. (hopefully within seconds)

To achieve the goal, **what would be the best option I could consider?**

---

**conditions**

1. Image Generate Service is scalable and image generation jobs are managed by queue. so there can be multiple services are running and the client cannot have 1 single destination to connect directly.
2. Generated images are not reusable. whenever user requests with some input, result images are different.
3. Those images cannot be pre-generated so we cannot store it first on S3 to serve it through CloudFront.
4. server location: us-west-1, client location: South Korea

---

**some trials**

I tried with some scenarios as below but I still expect there is some better way to achieve this goal.

1. Upload result file to S3 (public bucket) and provide for client with the key so that client can download it from S3 right after the file is uploaded.

   - tested with / without S3 Transfer acceleration
   - without acceleration, it is a bit slower than direct socket transferring. but interestingly, when I use acceleration, it is much faster than socket transferring although the file was not hit on CloudFront edge server.
2. Run separate WebSocket server so it can emit result image directly to clients.

   - concerns:

     - to make it scalable, not only image generate services but these WebSocket servers should be scalable. which requires client to know exact destination to receive expected result.
     - network bandwidth limitation to individual EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, and as I see in your case scenario, the best would be to go with something like GlusterFS in EC2. I'm using it to deliver some moodle data to final users, but the speed is definitely faster than using S3. You should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you are mentioning about shared file system so that I can store result image file from multiple workers, correct? how are you serving those files from EC2 to end user? and what protocol are you using? did you also configure NLB to that EC2 instance?

As far as I know most EC2 instance have 10Gbps of network bandwidth limit( I know it's varying per types though). wouldn't it be a bottleneck at some point?

Comment: The way Im using it atm is that I have two GlusterFS instances. For the application instances I have  an autoscaling template using an AMI with a t3a.xlarge machine. Minimum 3 maximum 30 instances. The GlusterFS environment is mounted on the instance template so I dont rely on a single EC2 to serve data to users